# Comparing two dates from a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, input

Somehow I can't get this to work. To me it seems correct and when i debug the code, my values are passed through correctly. Yet still the code does not enter the "alert" dialog box at all

```html
<input id="date1" type="text" class="form-control"
       placeholder="date 1" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">

<input id="date2" type="text" class="form-control"
       placeholder="date 2" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy"
       onchange="checkDate()">
```

```js
function checkDate() {
    var d1 = document.getElementById("date1").value;
    var d2 = document.getElementById("date2").value;
    if (d2 >= d1) {
        alert("date 2 is not allowed to be smaller than date 1")
    } else {
        //Success
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (d2 >= d1)` then print the error message? Isn't this a logic error? Shouldn't the `>=` symbol be `<=` instead?

Comment: I'm not getting an error message, it's just not showing the alert message as it should, when date 2 is before date 1. It shoudn't be allowed

Comment: Sorry. I wrote "error message" when what I meant was "alert message". But please answer my question about the `>=` symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do this:

```
function myStringToDate(str) {
  var arr  = str.split("/"); // split string at slashes to make an array
  var yyyy = arr[2] - 0; // subtraction converts a string to a number
  var jsmm = arr[1] - 1; // subtract 1 because stupid JavaScript month numbering
  var dd   = arr[0] - 0; // subtraction converts a string to a number 
  return new Date(yyyy, jsmm, dd); // this gets you your date
}
```

Then you will have the tool you need for this to work:

```
function checkDate() {
    var d1 = myStringToDate(document.getElementById("date1").value);
    var d2 = myStringToDate(document.getElementById("date2").value);
    if (d2.getTime() <= d1.getTime()) {
        alert("date 2 is not allowed to be smaller than date 1")
    } else {
        //Success
    }
}
```

Notice that I changed the comparison operator from `>=` to `<=` because it seemed that `<=` better matched your intent. If I was wrong about this, just change it back.

Answer (score 2):

you're comparing strings.

try converting the input to a [date](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) object like below:

```
d1 = new Date(document.getElementById("date1").value);
```

also there is a new input type in html5: "date"

 i recommend using that for your input tag.

example:

```
<input type="date" id="date1" date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" onchange="checkDate()"/>
```

Comment: You mean: `new Date(document.getElementById("date1").value)`?

Comment: if using the "date" type it works, i'll add an example input tag to the answer.

Comment: I can't use the "date" type, since it's im using a calender to populate the textfield with data

Comment: could you provide a sample of what the dates look like when the calendar populates the input? (13/12/2016 or 13-12-2016 or something else?)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a proper example of the HTML5 date field. I also renamed your variables to start and end date to make it easier to follow.

```js
function checkDate() {
  var dateForm  = document.forms['date-form'];
  var startDate = new Date(dateForm['start-date'].value);
  var endDate   = new Date(dateForm['end-date'].value);

  if (startDate >= endDate) {
    alert("End Date cannot occur before the Start Date!");
  } else {
    alert("Success!");
  }
}
```

```css
.form-field {
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.form-field label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
}
.form-field label:after {
  content: ': ';
}
```

```html
<form name="date-form">
  <div class="form-field">
    <label>Start Date</label>
    <input id="date1" type="date" class="form-control" name="start-date"
           format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label>End Date</label>
    <input id="date2" type="date" class="form-control" name="end-date"
           format="dd/mm/yyyy" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy" />
           <!-- onchange="checkDate()" -->
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Check" onClick="checkDate()" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class to compare dates:

```js
function checkDate() {
  var d1 = new Date(document.getElementById("date1").value);
  var d2 = new Date(document.getElementById("date2").value);

  if (d2.getTime() >= d1.getTime()) {
    alert("date 2 is not allowed to be smaller than date 1")
  } else {
    alert('//Success');
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="date1" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="date 1" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">

<input id="date2" type="text" class="form-control" onchange="checkDate()" placeholder="date 2" data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
```

Comment: Apparently, the asker expects the dates to be in `dd/mm/yyyy` format. Does your `checkDate()` function allow for this?

Comment: @Justinas I get a d1 = Invalid date error and the sam with d2

Comment: @RobertLozyniak Passed date format must be compatible with Data parser, but OP does not asks that